# Rust, make action after panic

Tags: rust, error-handling

I have a question about making an action after panic!. I have a strong experience with Python, and often I use:

```
try:
   do_something()
exception:
   do_something_else()
```

But I can't do that in Rust. My code is below:

```
fn do_something(value: u32) -> Result<u32, io::Error> {
    if value > 30 {
        panic!("Value is bigger then 30!");
    }
    else {
        Ok(value)
    }
}
// first try
fn if_else_catch(value: u32) -> Result<u32, u32> {
    let result = do_something(value);
    let something = match result {
        Ok(something) => something + something,
        Err(err) => do_something_else(),
    };

    Ok(something)
}

fn if_else_catch_retun_different_value(value: u32) -> Result<u32, u32> {
    let result = do_something(value);
    let something = match result {
        Ok(something) => something + something,
        Err(err) => 100,
    };

    Ok(something)
}
// another try
fn do_something_else_with_questionmark(value: u32) -> Result<u32, io::Error> {
    let result = do_something(value)?;
    if let Err(_err) = do_something(value) {
        println!("An Error occured!");
    }
    Ok(result)
}

fn main() {
    println!("Do something: {}", do_something(35).unwrap());
    println!("Do something res: {}", if_else_catch(35).unwrap());
}
```

Is it possible to do this?
How can I implement it?

I already checked the documentation, but an example like this:

```
let greeting_file_result = File::open("hello.txt");

    let greeting_file = match greeting_file_result {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(error) => panic!("Problem opening the file: {:?}", error),
    };
```

```
    ^
    |
```

doesn't work for this case.

Comment: For a recoverable error, you should return `Err(something)` instead of panicking.

Comment: You might like to read the [Error Handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) chapter of The Rust Programming Language.

Comment: In rust, it is more close at the Monads concept of Erlang. From python, you have an idea of wath is Monads at https://dev.to/nhradek/monads-in-python-4npa. In your case, I think is bad idea to use panic!(). Err() is better, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-03-to-panic-or-not-to-panic.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural thing would be to just return an `Err` in your error case:

```rust
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind};

fn do_something(value: u32) -> Result<u32, Error> {
    if value > 30 {
        Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Value is bigger than 30!"))
    } else {
        Ok(value)
    }
}
```

If you really have to you can use [`catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) to recover from panics but

> It is **not** recommended to use this function for a general try/catch mechanism. The `Result` type is more appropriate to use for functions that can fail on a regular basis. Additionally, this function is not guaranteed to catch all panics.

```rust
use std::panic::catch_unwind;
fn catch_it(value: u32) -> Result<u32, u32> {
    let result = catch_unwind(|| do_something(value));
    let something = match result {
        Ok(Ok(something)) => something + something,
        Ok(Err(_)) | Err(_) => do_something_else(),
    };

    Ok(something)
}
```

Comment: Definitely first example is enough for me, big thanks! :)